# Python без dll

Tags: python, c++

Всем привет, прошу совета.

В программе на C++ требуется скриптовый язык, для этих целей я выбрал пайтон. Но проблема в том, что он требует наличия своей dll, что не очень хорошо, так как крайне не хочется плодить кучу библиотек. Про то, что dll нужна для подключения внешних pyd я знаю, но могу гарантировать, что я не буду их подключать. Причем скриптовый интерпретатор будет таки в dll, просто мне надо, что бы перед передачей скрипта непосредственно пайтону была произведена предварительная его обработка. То есть в задачу этой dll будет принять на вход текст скрипта, произвести кое-какие манипуляции и отдать уже собственно интерпертатору.  <br>Вся задача пайтона сводится к управлению вызовом функций,предоставленных из вне. Вопрос вот в чем: есть ли способ собрать пайтон для статической линковки, что бы он был частью другой dll без необходимости использования PythonNN.dll?<br>
Смотрел в сторону boost.python, но он ругается на отсутствие pyconfig.h

Comment: pyconfig.h - пути пропиши правильные. А вообще тебе лучше подойдет lua имхо. Python слишком-тяжелый для того чтобы его интегрировать ради hello word.

Comment: Да я бы с удовольствием обошелся lua, но мне нужен юникод и юникодовские же регулярки.

Comment: @ChinYan, а стандартный (из libc) POSIX regcomp() и regexec() чем не устраивают ? 

Может просто установить правильно setlocale() ?

Comment: Нужно дать пользователю возможность использовать регулярки, а не в принципе их использовать

Comment: @ChinYan, совсем не понял, почему у пользователя пропадет возможность использования регулярок, если их взять из родной (libc) библиотеки.

Comment: Потому что тогда придется прикручивать промежуточные функции в lua,которые будут вызывать уже исходные регулярки - короче, развлекуха еще та. В питоне же с регулярками проще. А у луы мутно с юникодом. Потому что планируются функции, которым на вход подаются именно юникодные строки. С равным успехом функция может и вернуть юникодную строку..

Comment: @ChinYan, а причем здесь lua ??? 

Я говорю о regcomp() и regexec() из libc (стандартно присутствует в C++).

Comment: Да при том, что нужно из скрипта иметь возможность использовать регулярки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Попробую ответить на исходный вопрос, а не принимать участие в споре "`X` или `Y` лучше для `U`".)*

- Собрать `python` как статическую библиотеку и прилинковать ее действительно возможно. Сложнее, нежели сделать `1-command-install`, как это делается при применении `bjam`, но не намного сложнее обычной возни с `./configure make install`.
- Больше того, поскольку `boost::python` является просто гибкой оберткой над [обычными функциями, предоставляемыми `python`,](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/extending/embedding.html) то можно использовать и его. Единственная разница будет в том, что в вашем случае `python` не будет линковаться из коробки, а придется кое-что поднастроить.

  ```
      # On Windows, all code using Python has to link to the Python
      # import library.
      #
      # On *nix we never link libboost_python to libpython.  When
      # extending Python, all Python symbols are provided by the
      # Python interpreter executable.  When embedding Python, the
      # client executable is expected to explicitly link to
      # /python//python (the target representing libpython) itself.
  ```
- Итак, допустим, [вы потанцевали с бубном](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150373/compile-the-python-interpreter-statically), собрали `python` статически. Я осуществлял сборку под **`Windows 7 / MinGW`** и с точностью до конфигурирования через `./configure` и настройки модулей проблем с этим не возникло.
- Далее - как сообщить `boost::python`, что вы собираетесь линковать `python` статически. Судя по всему, *(здесь могу ошибаться)* `boost::python` не предоставляет механизма для линковки статической библиотеки `python` и всегда предполагает работу со случаем `shared library`.
- Обойти данное ограничение несложно - в `boost` используется кроссплатформенный собственный механизм подключения библиотек, поэтому, если вы попытаетесь собрать проект с `boost::python` без дополнительных телодвижений, вы увидите ошибку из разряда `cannot open file 'python27.lib'.` Собственно, `boost::python` предполагает, что в этот момент линковка будет происходить со `static import library`, но вы можете обмануть его, подсунув ему библиотеку, полученную в результате статической сборки `python`.

> Для случая `*nix` надо проверять отдельно, судя по доке сверху, там `libpython` линковать придется руками *(не проверял).*

- **Не могу судить о том, насколько данный подход допустим и корректен *(прогнал только `quick test` из разряда `A + B`)*.**

---

- Про общие проблемы использования статической линковки и про конкретную ограничения `python` вы, как я понял, уже знаете, поэтому про эту тему говорить, я думаю, не стоит.

> While the `configure` script shipped
>     with the `Python` sources will correctly
>   build `Python` to export the symbols
>   needed by dynamically linked
>   extensions, this is not automatically
>   inherited by applications which embed
>   the `Python` library statically, at
>   least on Unix. This is an issue when
>   the application is linked to the
>   static runtime library *(`libpython.a`)*
>   and needs to load dynamic extensions
>   *(implemented as `.so` files).*

- Некоторые дополнительные референсы по теме:

> - [**Compile the static `boost` libraries in `Windows`.**](http://wiki.thedarkmod.com/index.php?title=Compile_the_static_Boost_Libraries_in_Windows)
> - [**How to link project with a specified `libpython` in static.**](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/how-to-link-project-with-a-specified-libpython-in-static-using-boost-Python-td2701737.html)

Comment: Вот почему я вас уважаю и стремлюсь быть как вы @Котик ...

Comment: Вот почему никто не может ответить столь же развернуто?! Сколько ни мучился, нигде такого ответа не получил

Comment: Возможно (проверьте сами) добавление ключа -rdynamic (gcc) при статической сборке позволит питоновским функциям из .so модулей обращаться к статически слинкованным питоновсим функциям.

Для своих в a.out из libxaxa.so после dlopen(libxaxa) после сборки a.out с -rdynamic обращаться можно.

@ChinYan, а Вы уврены, что Вам Питон на самом деле нужен ? Если только из-за регулярок, то IMHO можно и попроще.

Comment: @ChinYan Ну лично я просто в принципе не мог обойти стороной вопрос, так или иначе связанный с `boost'ом` :)

Comment: Вообще, мне нужны юникодовские регулярки (ну и юникодоские строки, естественно) и возможность вызова функций, предоставленных прогой

Comment: А с пифоном статически линковаться можно вообще?

Comment: В этом и вопрос

Comment: Я имел ввиду ограничения, накладываемые лицензией...

Comment: @karmadro4 Крутой, кстати, вопрос. Я в `GPL`-подобных лицензиях не очень хорошо разбираюсь, так что было бы здорово, если бы кто-нибудь просветил насчет этого аспекта.

Comment: @Котик, там не GPL, а скорее BSD-подобная [лицензия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Software_Foundation_License)

Comment: @neoascetic Да, я под `GPL`-подобной имел ввиду `GPL compatible`, а это, естественно, совсем не одно и то же. Надо сказать, что вопросы совместимости такого рода лицензий и тысячи всяких деталей и тонкостей `GPL2`, `GPL3, `BSD` и т.д. - это все суровейшая жесть и надо будет как-нибудь разобраться поподробнее :)

Comment: Да уж лучше один раз разобраться :)

Меня позабавил чеклист при выборе лицензии для python-пакета в [dive into python](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/diveintopython3/html/packaging.html#cantdo)